# writing azure-friendly asp.net

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm building an asp.net application that will be deployed on Azure. For the moment, I'm using regular asp.net: I'm building it in VS.

I have a web service that's in an asxm file MyService.asmx with a code behind file MyService.cs that calls a different class library called MyBigClass.cs that does most of the work.

If I want to prepare for a deployment on Azure in a few months and make that web service work in its own web role that I can scale based on usage load, should I put the classes that are in the MyBigClass.cs file into the MyService.cs file? The MyBigClass.cs file contains classes that are used for other parts of the application as well; should I remove these classes and only include the ones used by the web service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to give a specific answer, and to be honest - I don't think the answer to this would be Windows-Azure-specific, but rather - this is simply a design best practice question, isn't it?

It comes down to how you will go about maintaining the application, and how you are going to manage versioning, but generally speaking - code that isn't shared does not need to get deployed to both roles, so either move it back with the 'parnet' solution (web app or service), or keep in a separate assembly which you will deploy with only the relevant role.

Code that is shared between the web app and service will exist in a shared assembly which you will deploy into both roles.

So you might end up with the following projects

- A web site
- An assembly supporting the web site
- A Web service Service
- An assembly supporting the web service
- A shared assembly between the web site and web service

I hope this makes sense